# Retrieve outer most points on a 2d graph

Tags: algorithm, math, 2d

G'day everyone,

I have a 2d graph which has some points plotted on it. 
What I need to do is get only the outer most points so that I can connect them up (isn't really relevant).

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is the algorithm that I need to use in order to do this?

---

I think this might help you understand what I want to achieve:

```
o o o
o x o
o o o
```

All the o's I want to get and the x I want to ignore. Also, the points can be in any position and any shape but I still want to only grab the outer most points.

Any ideas?

Also, I am not sure if this is the correct site to ask this on so if its not, please let me know where to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the set of points that you have. I personally prefer to use [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) for this as it is fairly easy to implement and has good computational complexity.

Answer (score 2):

if your 2d graph is represented by set of XY coordinates, you can compute the convex hull as Ivaylo mentioned.

if your graph is similar to your example in the post, which is represented by a 2d grid map, you can use floodfill to get the boundary.

Comment: This is what it looks like so I am guessing the convex hull would be the best solution, thanks for your answer! [Image](http://i.imgur.com/BgNWw.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve this in javascript, have a look at d3.js geom.hull: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hull-Geom